# Why is there a Java radix limit?

Tags: java

I noticed that the max limit for a radix in Java is base 36. 
Is this an arbitrary limit, or does Java have reason for limiting the radix in this way?

Comment: What would you expect the 37th digit in base 37 to be?

Comment: Because we didn't want to start using non-letters and non-digits to represent numbers ;)

Comment: Load up a classic Forth that accepts ASCII strings. Set BASE to 256. Everything typed at the interpreter is now a number that gets put on the stack. Whee!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the number of decimal digits (10), plus the number of letters in the alphabet (26).

If a radix of 37 were allowed, a new character would have to be picked to represent the 37th digit. While it certainly would have been *possible* to pick some character, there is no *obvious* choice. It makes sense to just disallow larger radixes.

Comment: Of course, some languages, such as Bash shell arithmetic, allow higher radixes (radices?) by distinguishing uppercase letters from lowercase when the radix is greater than 36. Java does not do this.

Comment: Exactly. So why did Java base the maximum radix on case-insensitive alpha-numeric instead of case-sensitive alpha-numeric? It seems dumb to throw away 26 numerals.

Comment: What about a capitalized A ?

Comment: If you make capital and lowercase different, which is the higher value, `A` or `a`? Again, it's easy to pick one, but it would be an arbitrary choice - there is no *obvious* choice. Also traditionally hex survives case changes -- 0x8a == 0x8A; it would be confusing to have some bases in which that doesn't apply.

Nonetheless, you can achieve base 62 by using 0-9a-zA-Z -- you just can't do it with `Integer.toString()`

Comment: Which comes first, `0` or `a`? Arbitrary! Not obvious!

Comment: In ASCII, `0`, in EBCDIC, `a`!

Comment: From Wikipedia's article on Hexadecimals: _The now-current notation using the letters A to F establishes itself as the de-facto standard beginning in 1966, in the wake of the publication of the Fortran IV manual for IBM System/360 [...]_ --- So back then, it has been arbitrary and to many also non-obvious - but I'm sure by the end of the century, it was the expected order for anyone familiar with hex numbers.

Comment: Yes, I think the *feature* of case-insensitivity of numeric constants is the more significant reason.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple: 26 letters + 10 digits = 36.

In order to represent a number, traditionally digits and Latin letters are used.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I would add that there are two constants defined in JDK:

```
Character.MIN_RADIX
Character.MAX_RADIX
```

Answer (score 0):

Radix limit make sense if the output has to be readable.
In various case, the output does NOT need to be readable.
Thus indeed, a higher limit would help in such cases.
And the java langage radix limit is a weak point for java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Base64` encoding scheme as specified in RFC 4648 and RFC 2045.

Just generate the byte representation of you int number according you needs, to be compatible with the majority of the libraries that implement Base64.

Answer (score -2):

I have found somewhere in Internet - I don't know where - that there are bases or radices from 2 to 62 in Positional Numbering System.

Bases 2 to 10 uses digits only

Bases 11 to 36 uses digits and capital letters

Bases 37 to 62 uses digits, capital letters and small letters

10 digits in Hindu Arabic System + 26 capital letters of English + 26 small letters of English = 62 characters in all

I think Java should upgrade itself and should have limit till base 62 and not base 36.

Talking about Bijective Bases in this way which do not use zero (0) as a digit - their radix starts from base 1 till 61.

And for Balanced Bases (digits include both negative and positive numbers and letters in equal quantity including 0), we should have from base 3 till base 62 + 62 - 1 = 123 (ignoring repetition of zero)

For even bases n (say), base (n + 1) digits will be used such that every number have unique representation with the digits. But, only such base I know is balanced base 2.

There is Excel Spreadsheet Column Heading Number System which uses only capital letters where A = 1, B = 2, ... till Z = 26. This is also a Positional Number System.

There is a Non-Hindu Arabic Related Number System i.e., Roman Numerals which uses I for 1, V for 5, X for 10, L for 50, C for 100, D for 500, M for 1000, horizontal bars for multiplication by 1000, double horizontal bars for multiplication by 10^6 and so on, allowing additive and subtractive rules of representation and repetition till 3 times (excluding M for being repeated 4 times).

Comment: You can use bases beyond 62. Though it may be difficult to find a symbol set for those.

Comment: Here's the link for base 64: https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1457585550-How-does-Base64-work

Comment: They are random characters for 63rd and 64th digit. Here، in this link, they are using plus (+) and slash (/). But, in Wikiversity, they are using hyphen or minus (-) and underscore (_). So, we can use random characters and then extend number system beyond 62. You are correct, Ouroborus.

Comment: The question is "why does Java have this limit?", not "should there be a limit?"

Comment: Maybe this is going to wrong direction. I am just telling that there are bases beyond 62 in Positional Numbering System and there are other number systems. I am not forcing Java to add these bases in their programming language.

Comment: I am just giving a suggestion to Java, not enforcing them. Maybe people used to have only bases from 2 to 36 in old times, that is why, java just have these many bases.